# How to "touch" a file with timestamp in UTC?

Tags: shell, unix, time, touch

On my system I have to run `touch -t '197001010100' filename` to get stat timestamp of 0 seconds.

I assume the 1 hour offset is due to my timezone, is there a cross-Unix way to touch a file and get zero tiemstamp, as in Unix Epoch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `TZ=UTC` before these commands to make sure to use `UTC` timezone:

```
TZ=UTC touch -t '197001010000' filename
TZ=UTC stat -c '%y %n' filename
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0000 filename
```

**PS:** Also you need use timestamp as `197001010000` instead of `197001010100`.

Comment: **+1**  Very handy.  Didn't know that `touch` would respect `$TZ.`

Comment: Cool, I've done that too; Does it work on all Unix'es and all implementations of touch or only GNU coreutils?

Comment: It should work on all Unix flavors as there is nothing GNU specific here. I tested it myself on OSX.

Comment: The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html#tag_20_130_08) mandates that `touch` shall respect `TZ`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, this is exactly the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu:

```
date +%s | xargs touch
```

or

```
touch "$(date +%s)"
```

The second one is more flexible in that you can append or prepend extra text, like

```
touch "log_$(date +%s)"
```

Comment: `date +%s` is not the format `touch` using, the correct one should be `date +'%Y%m%d%H%M.%S'`